# phpMyAdmin single quote not return result

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone = 60123456789
```

phpMyAdmin return result but when I try :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone = '60123456789'
```

phpMyAdmin return an empty result. The column type varchar.

How do I make it working with single quote? Am I wrongly set the type in structure?

Comment: how is the value in the database itself? is it exactly `60123456789`?

Comment: got thousand of data but most of them is 11 digit number.. I need it as varchar because some data contains + in front of that.. currently I just make it varchar(255)

Comment: My Q's 1) Do you have That record in DB ? 2) Can you paste your Table record here ? 3) can you Paste you ERROR here ?

Comment: 3) the phpMyAdmin only return empty. No error. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone like '60123456789%'
```

If that works then you have trailing spaces in your column

You can remove them using

```
update user set phone = replace(phone, ' ', '')
```

### Edit

Example:

Trailing spaces:

```
'123  '
```

Leading spaces:

```
'  123'
```

Comment: Will you tell me what is trailing space??

Comment: trailing space is whitespaces after. leading spaces is whitespaces before.

Comment: it's actually not trailing space but trailing alien character at every phone number. Still don't know what character it is, can't see it. I tried your suggestion and change it to varchar(11), remove all + sign. It is working now.

Comment: when I export the data, I found \r as trailing character. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change column type varchar in structure from  `varchar` to `int` if you are using only integer values.

Then both will work

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone = 60123456789

SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone = '60123456789'
```

**UPDATE** Mine is working with Varchar(225)

like

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_practice` 
WHERE  `name` =  '+5734563656546'
LIMIT 0 , 30

SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_practice` 
WHERE  `name` =  +5734563656546
LIMIT 0 , 30


SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_practice` 
WHERE  `name` =  5734563656546
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

*I don't Know why are you facing this problem ?*

Comment: some data contains +60123456789 (plus)

Comment: @user1385778 maybe it could be useful to sanitize your data then, so that all or none contain a `+`. Or, alternatively, `WHERE PHONE LIKE '%60123456789'` - but this search cannot use indexes, so it is very bad.